# compilation error while using constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, int N>
int ReturnArraySize(T (&arg1)[N]) {
    return N;
}

constexpr int ReturnTheSum(int arg1, int arg2) {
    return arg1 + arg2;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int arr1[20];
    int arr2[ReturnArraySize(arr1)];
    int arr3[ReturnTheSum(ReturnArraySize(arr1), ReturnArraySize(arr2))];

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code, I get the following error:

> /root/Documents/C++11_Fundamentals/ConstExprRelatedFunc/main.cpp:19:67: error: no matching function for call to '`ReturnArraySize(int [(<anonymous> + 1)])`'

Comment: I want to know the reason why this error is coming

Answer (score 2):

Because `ReturnArraySize` is not marked as a `constexpr` function, `arr2` becomes a VLA ([variable-length array](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), a GCC extension, not part of the C++ standard), which cannot be queried for its size at compile time (i.e., deduced by a function template).

You can fix this by making `ReturnArraySize` a `constexpr`:

```
template <typename T, int N>
constexpr int ReturnArraySize(T (&arg1)[N]) {
//~~~~~~^
    return N;
}
```

Comment: Thanks my issue got fixed